# nxlog get logs from applications and services logs

Tags: windows, nxlog

i am having issues getting data of an event log , located on   the applications and services Logs. I have put a query in the nxlog conf file that get the erros,warning,critical logs from the application event log but it doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated

I am trying to get the Stream event file in application and service logs see following screenshot
 [screen_shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuYcT.png)

Here is my nxlog conf for the input

```
<Input eventlog>
 Module      im_msvistalog       
Query   <QueryList>\ <Query Id="0" Path="Application">\ <Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3)]]</Select> </Query>\ </QueryList> 
 </Input>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check `nxlog.log` for any errors.
To me it looks like the `Query` line is incorrect as there should be a linebreak after each `\`.

Comment: i went to check the nxlog.log and it says that  the query is malfunctioned.No idea why